# How to initialize Material Web V3 Components

Tags: material-design, material-components-web

How to initialize Material Web V3 Components,
e.g I want to create a text field:

```
<md-filled-text-field label="Label" value="Value"></md-filled-text-field>
```

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@material/web@1.0.1/all.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <md-filled-text-field label="Label" value="Value"></md-filled-text-field>
</body>
</html>
```

The error I get is the following:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "tslib". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".